# Show which files has changed in SmartGit

Tags: git, smartgit

I would like to see which files have changed between the latest commit and the selected commit. I can do it in the command line like so:

```
 git diff --name-only 1f507b3cad799cff52a18ec9c132e25c0c4c21da
```

Can SmartGit do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open SmartGit's **Log** and select both commits in the **Commits** graph. **Reveal Commit** and **Compare with Selected Commit** actions from the **Branches** context menu may be helpful here. The files which are different will be displayed in the **Files** view and you may investigate individual file changes by selecting a file there and checking the **Changes** view.